# Why the ShellFeedsTaskbarViewMode registry value unable to change

Tags: windows, registry

I'm facing a weird situation about editing the registry value.

I record an video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Au8NRF-SMDY

It because I want to turn off `News and interests` feeds by changing Registry directly. I'm changing a registry value from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Feeds` key and the `ShellFeedsTaskbarViewMode` value from `2` to `0`. After the value changed without any error, I hit the `Refresh` (F5) immediately. Then the value changed back. I don't know what's going on. Does anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer from Ill_Branch1293 worked for me : https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/s1iomh/comment/hw0soe4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Here is the code:

```
# Turn off News and Interests

Write-Host "Turning off News and Interests..."

TASKKILL /IM explorer.exe /F

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Feeds" -Name "ShellFeedsTaskbarViewMode" -Type DWord -Value 2

Start-Process explorer.exe
```